# Prepositional /infinitive phrase as sentence connectors

Tags: grammar

When prepositional phrases and infinitive phrases are used as sentence connectors i.e. they come at the beginning of the sentence, what is their status in the sentence? Are they mere connectors or are they also an integral part of the sentence they introduce?

Example: **He is a hardworking man. Apart from this, he is also very diligent.** Here is "apart from this" only a connector or also an integral part of the sentence "he is also very diligent?

Similarly, **He wants to be rich. To achieve his objective, he is working very hard.** Is "To achieve his objective" only a connector or also an integral part of the sentence "he is woking very hard" acting as an adverbial?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A prepositional/infinitive phrase is not an integral part of the sentence. In both examples above, if you take out the prepositional/infinitive, the meaning wouldn't change. Allow me to show you:

"He is a hardworking man. Apart from this, he is also very diligent" is the original phrase, right? Now let's look at what we get if we remove the prepositional/infinitive.

"He is a hard working man. He is also very diligent" the connector served to give context and meaning to the second sentence based on the premise of the first, i.e, the connector is there to make sure the second sentence talks about the same subject as the first. However, if we remove it, the result stays the same. The second sentence still talks about the subject introduced in the first, therefore, it is not essential to comprehend that our subject is a) a hardworking man and b) very diligent.

With the second example, the same happens.

> "He wants to be rich. To achieve his objective, he is working very
>   hard"

turns to:

> "He wants to be rich. He is working very hard"

The fact that the context of the second sentence (that he works very hard) is directly related to the first is not lost because the prepositional/infinitive is removed. The meaning stays perfectly clear and could be removed without altering the meaning of either sentence nor the meaning of the two combined.

Comment: If the logic is that the meaning shouldn't be altered, then how come subordinating conjunctions and conjunctive adverbs which are also connectors and whose removal doesn't alter the meaning of sentence, are considered to be integral to the clause of which they are part. Conjunctive adverbs even modify the entire clause of which it is part. Thanks

Comment: Hello,  Can some enlightened minds throw some light on the above? Thanks